# Invariants of general linear groups under torus action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G=GL_n$ be the general linear group (let's say over an algebraically closed field of char $=0$). Let's denote as $T$ the torus of diagonal matrices: is there an explicit description of the invariant functions $$\mathbb{C}[G \times G]^T $$ where $T$ acts by simultaneous conjugation?

Comment: This ring contains the ring of invariant functions under the simultaneous action of the full conjugation by $G$, and this ring is generated by the traces of words in the two "letters" and their inverses (I believe this is a result of Procesi).  Perhaps your ring is similarly generated by the individual diagonal entries of these words (in addition to the trace, which is the sum of the diagonal entries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the two matrices ${}_1A$ and ${}_2A$.

Your ring can be expressed by taking the $T$-invariants of the free ring in $2n^2$ variables $\mathbb C[{}_kA_{ij}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n, 1\leq k \leq 2}$ and then inverting $\det {}_1 A$ and $\det {}_2 A$.

The $T$-invariants of the free ring are the ring of functions on an affine toric variety. It has an explicit combinatorial structure. A basis for it is given by the $T$-invariant monomials.

A generating set is given by the monomials that can't be decomposed into two monomials.  These have the following form: For $k \leq n$ a natural number, $i_1,\dots ,i_k$ distinct indices from $1$ to $n$, and $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_k$ values from $1$ to $2$, the element $$ \prod_{j=1}^k {}_{\epsilon_j}A_{i_j i_{j+1}}$$ is such a monomial, and it's not too hard to see how they have this form.

To see the ring has this form, simply note that any function on $G \times G$ is a polynomial in the entries divided by some power of the two determinants, and since the determinants are $T$-invariant, any invariant polynomial must be an invariant polynomial in the entries divided by some power of the two determinants.